# JQuery: Calling the input value by an ID

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to get the value of the input id="registration_type"

I type on console:

> $('#registration_type')

then it will appear:

```
<input id=​"registration_type" name=​"contact_registration[type]​" type=​"hidden" value=​"ContactRegistration">​
```

I want to get the value only which is "ContactRegistration"
How will I do that on JQuery?

Comment: `$('#registration_type').val()`

Comment: $('#registration_type').val()

Answer (score 1):

You need to use

```
$('#registration_type').val();
```

Answer (score 1):

USE [**.val() Method of jQuery**](http://api.jquery.com/val/):

```
$('#registration_type').val()
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/7NV78/)

Answer (score 0):

you are missing val() of jquery .

```
$('#registration_type').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

$('#registration_type').value;
If you can get it as whole object, it means you are able to access its property.

Answer (score 0):

using $('#registration_type') you get dom element. Now from this element you can fetch any property or function.

for value of $('#registration_type') you need to

```
$('#registration_type').val()
```